# Install kafka on windowns returns ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper

When I run this command in cmd to start Zookeeper on windows

```
PS D:\Users\e.akbar\Downloads\confluent-community-7.0.1\confluent-7.0.1\bin\windows> .\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
```

But I get this error :

```
PS D:\Users\e.akbar\Downloads\confluent-community-7.0.1\confluent-7.0.1\bin\windows> .\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
[2022-01-25 13:26:02,943] INFO Reading configuration from: .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2022-01-25 13:26:02,944] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:198) 
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:124)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties file is missing
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.doFailForNonExistingPath(VerifyingFileFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.validate(VerifyingFileFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.create(VerifyingFileFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:180)
        ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
[2022-01-25 13:26:02,948] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
[2022-01-25 13:26:02,950] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 2 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be this :

```
 .\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Confluent does not support running their services on Windows.

If you must use a windows host, use WSL2 https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Related post [Unable to produce to Kafka topic that is running on WSL 2 from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177422/unable-to-produce-to-kafka-topic-that-is-running-on-wsl-2-from-windows/65553634#65553634)

Comment: @Recently I have run this service on windows .

Comment: @Ehsan Zookeeper may start, but Kafka will (eventually) start throwing filesystem permission errors