# Connect to Kafka running in WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kafka-producer-api

The below is my Kafka broker configuration

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
host.name=127.0.0.1
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Console producer and consumer are working perfectly but when I try to connect through Java, it is throwing broker not available error. The Kafka broker is running and able to produce and consume messages through console.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);

producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("Sample","Hey","From java program"));
producer.close();
```

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I'm using STS IDE to write Java program and using Java 8, Kafka 2.8.1
Windows OS and using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS to execute console producer and consumer.

Comment: Where is your Kafka broker running?

Comment: my kafka is running on this port in my local 127.0.0.1:9092

Comment: right, but which machine? You've mentioned windows and ubuntu

Comment: Started kafka server using Ubuntu and tested console producer and consumer. Written sample kafka producer and consumer in STS (in windows 10) and trying to connect to the same kafka which was started using ubuntu LTS. Do i need to start the same kafka in windows again using .bat files and then try connecting through java kafka producer?

Comment: That wouldn't be recommended, no. You'll have other issues running Kafka in windows directly. Instead, if you really don't want to deal with networking configurations, you need to run your code in WSL2 as well. In other words, localhost is not the same between Windows and the hypervisor running Kafka.

Comment: Thank you so much OneCricketeer. I'm able to make it work if I run the code in WSL2.

Answer (score 4):

Too late for this response, but hope this helps someone.

- Identify the ip address of the WSL2 using ifconfig or ip addr or hostname -I
- From the windows command prompt (as admin) run below command

```
> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9092 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9092 connectaddress=172.X.X.X
```

172.X.X.X is the Ip of the WSL2

With that change I was able to access the Kafka cluster.

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738246/3192775)